# Even Power Series properties

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, convergence-divergence, power-series

Let $$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}h_kx^k$$ be a series with convergence radius $R>0$ and sum function $s:(-R,R)\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$.

- Show that if $h_{2k+1}=0$ for alle $k\geq 0$ then $s$ is even and that
  $$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}h_k(1-(-1)^k)x^k$$ has a sum $s(x)-s(-x)$.

Use the uniqueness of a power series to conclude that if $s$ is even, then $h_{2k+1}=0$ for all $n\geq0$.

---

I know that a function is even if $g(x)=g(-x)$. Furthermore, I knwo that for 2 $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_nx^n,\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}b_nx^n$ that both have convergence radius (atleast) $r>0$ and that $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_nx^n=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}b_nx^n$$
holds for all $x\in (-r,r)$ then $a_n=b_n$ for all $n\in \mathbb{N_0}$.

Even though I understand these results I am struggeling solving this problem as it seems vague; i.e not specific.

Comment: Hint: If $h_{2n+1}=0$ for all $n\geq0$, then $H(-x)=\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}h_{2n}(-x)^{2n}=\ldots=H(x)$ so that $H$ is even.

Comment: 1. Is $H = s$? 2. You know $s(-x) = \sum_k h_k(-x)^k$?

Comment: @Nicolas I have looked at it for hours but I still do not see the argument. I am unsure on what you are doing to achieve that answer.

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang I am not sure on what you are asking, unfortunately..

Comment: 1. The first line contains a symbol $H$ that does not appear again. Is $H$ the same thing as $s$...? 2. If $s(x) = \sum_{k} h_{k}x^{k}$ is a convergent power series, we can substitute any expression for $x$ that lies in the interval of convergence, such as $-x$. <> If property 2. is not familiar, it will help to say what you know about power series.

Comment: @user879295 I have posted an answer, hope it is clearer.

Comment: I am not informed more about $H$. It is only used to argue that a function is even if  $H(x)=H(-x)$. The sum function (series representation $s$ is what I have to consider. This is my confusion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume that $H:(-R,R)\to\mathbb{R}$ is even: for all $x\in(-R,R)$, $H(-x)=H(x)$ \emph{i.e.}
\begin{align*}
H(-x)&=\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}h_n(-x)^n=\sum_{k=0}^{+\infty}h_{2k}(-x)^{2k}+\sum_{k=0}^{+\infty}h_{2k+1}(-x)^{2k+1}=\sum_{k=0}^{+\infty}h_{2k}x^{2k}-\sum_{k=0}^{+\infty}h_{2k+1}x^{2k+1},\\
H(x)&=\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}h_nx^n=\sum_{k=0}^{+\infty}h_{2k}x^{2k}+\sum_{k=0}^{+\infty}h_{2k+1}x^{2k+1}.
\end{align*}
This yields after subtracting the second line from the first one:
\begin{align*}
0&=H(-x)-H(x)=-\sum_{k=0}^{+\infty}h_{2k+1}x^{2k+1}-\sum_{k=0}^{+\infty}h_{2k+1}x^{2k+1}=-2\sum_{k=0}^{+\infty}h_{2k+1}x^{2k+1}.
\end{align*}
The sum $\widetilde{H}$ of the series $\sum h_{2k+1}x^{2k+1}$ is thus identically zero over $(-R,R)$. As
\begin{align*}
h_{2k+1}&=\frac{1}{(2k+1)!}\widetilde{H}^{(2k+1)}(0)
\end{align*}
and $\widetilde{H}\equiv0$, we deduce that $h_{2k+1}=0$ for all $k\in\mathbb{N}$.

Assume conversely that $h_{2k+1}=0$ for all $k\in\mathbb{N}$. Then for all $x\in(-R,R)$,
\begin{align*}
H(x)&=\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}h_nx^n=\sum_{k=0}^{+\infty}h_{2k}x^{2k}+\sum_{k=0}^{+\infty}\underbrace{h_{2k+1}}_{=0}x^{2k+1}=\sum_{k=0}^{+\infty}h_{2k}x^{2k},\\
H(-x)&=\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}h_n(-x)^n=\sum_{k=0}^{+\infty}h_{2k}(-x)^{2k}+\sum_{k=0}^{+\infty}\underbrace{h_{2k+1}}_{=0}(-x)^{2k+1}=\sum_{k=0}^{+\infty}h_{2k}(-x)^{2k}=\sum_{k=0}^{+\infty}h_{2k}x^{2k}
\end{align*}
i.e. $H(-x)=H(x)$ and $H$ is even.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/126143/discussion-on-answer-by-nicolas-even-power-series-properties).

Comment: I apologize. Kind of new here. I have asked in there now. I thought it was closed